# MYSQL Password Settings

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, password

Is there a command that I could use to check the password settings for MySQL without looking into each account? I'm trying to get password max length, min length, lockout threshold, password history, expiration date and etc.

I'm using MySQL 5.1.50.

Answer (score 1):

The password is encrypted via a one-way algorithm.  You cannot discover the length or contents (numbers, punctuation, etc) of passwords once they are stored.

Password rules need to be enforced when they are first created, even before touching MySQL.

If you want expiration rules that are easily configured and maintained, upgrade to 5.7.  (Anyway 5.1 is antique by now!)